# python pandas new column categorization based on conditions in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

Working with the following python pandas dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': ['A123','A123','B345','B345','C567','C567','D678','D678'], 
                   'product_id': [255472, 251235, 253764,257344,221577,209809,223551,290678],
                   'product_category': ['X','X','Y','Y','X','Y','Y','X']})

transaction_id | product_id | product_category
A123              255472             X
A123              251235             X
B345              253764             Y
B345              257344             Y
C567              221577             X
C567              209809             Y
D678              223551             Y
D678              290678             X
```

I need to add another column "transaction_category", which looks at the transaction_id and which product categories are in the transaction_id. 
This is the output I am looking for:

```
transaction_id | product_id | product_category | transaction_id
123              255472             X                X only
123              251235             X                X only
345              253764             Y                Y only
345              257344             Y                Y only
567              221577             X                X & Y
567              209809             Y                X & Y
678              223551             Y                X & Y
678              290678             X                X & Y
```

Please note that I have other columns in my dataframe that I am not using, so I guess I need to start with a grouby?

```
df2 = df.groupby(['transaction_id','product_category']).reset_index()
```

Comment: It helps the people who might answer this question if you include what you tried already and explain why the output wasn't satisfactory. Also, links to other questions or documentation that didn't answer your question help too.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I have to admit I couldn't find a helpful answer, but I will provide more links and explanations in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC by using `transform` and `join`

```
df.groupby('transaction_id').product_category.transform(lambda x : '&'.join(set(x)))
Out[468]: 
0      X
1      X
2      Y
3      Y
4    X&Y
5    X&Y
6    X&Y
7    X&Y
Name: product_category, dtype: object
```

From scott match your expected out put :

```
df['transaction_category']=df.groupby('transaction_id')['product_category'].transform(lambda x: x + ' only' if len(set(x)) < 2 else ' & '.join(set(x)))
df
Out[479]: 
  product_category  product_id transaction_id transaction_category
0                X      255472           A123               X only
1                X      251235           A123               X only
2                Y      253764           B345               Y only
3                Y      257344           B345               Y only
4                X      221577           C567                X & Y
5                Y      209809           C567                X & Y
6                Y      223551           D678                X & Y
7                X      290678           D678                X & Y
```

Comment: `df.groupby('transaction_id')['product_category'].transform(lambda x: x + ' only' if len(set(x)) < 2 else ' & '.join(set(x)))` maybe?

Comment: @ScottBoston that is match the expected out put , thank you man

Comment: thank you and to add it as a column, this is correct? df['transaction_category']=df.groupby('transaction_id')['product_category'].transform(lambda x: x + ' only' if len(set(x)) < 2 else ' & '.join(set(x)))

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @jeangelj yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 4):

the `transform` method of the `groupby` object allows your to add full-length columns back to your dataframe via `assign`:

```
import pandas

def squeezer(x):
    _x = list(set(x.values))
    if len(_x) == 1:
        return '{} only'.format(_x[0])
    else:
        return ' & '.join(sorted(_x))

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'transaction_id': ['A123','A123','B345','B345','C567','C567','D678','D678'], 
    'product_id': [255472, 251235, 253764,257344,221577,209809,223551,290678],
    'product_category': ['X','X','Y','Y','X','Y','Y','X']
}).assign(
    products=lambda df:
            df.groupby(by=['transaction_id'])['product_category']
              .transform(squeezer)
)
```

And we get:

```
  product_category  product_id transaction_id products
0                X      255472           A123   X only
1                X      251235           A123   X only
2                Y      253764           B345   Y only
3                Y      257344           B345   Y only
4                X      221577           C567    X & Y
5                Y      209809           C567    X & Y
6                Y      223551           D678    X & Y
7                X      290678           D678    X & Y
```

Comment: Thank you - I see that this is a function that uses transform and join; what is the benefit over Wen's way? I appreciate the feedback as I am trying to learn best practices and make my code as re-usable as possible

Comment: I'm just incorporating the column back in to your dataframe in a single chained assignment. Wen's answer produces the same series, but it still needs to be added to your dataframe.

Comment: I see; would this work too df['transaction_category']=df.groupby('transaction_id').product_category.transform(lambda x : '&'.join(set(x)))

Comment: @jeangelj try it and let us know

Comment: it worked for me, but now I am worried that it's incorrect; it's a large data set, but my value_counts() looked right

Comment: try it on your toy dataset. it should work, but I'm just trying to encourage you to experiment with python. the actual interpreter is more reliable than the human memory